# Python 3.7 vs 2.7, assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a bit of a 2.7 Python person. I came across this code, which I can assume what it does, but what does it exactly mean? Model is used, but I assume that model is a variable that is of the type of class, but then we assign a function to it. Looks very odd to me.

```
model: Class = a_function(f)
```

What does the above mean?

Comment: That's a function call, not a function, just like in 2.x.

Comment: The function is being called so the return value is assigned

Comment: [PEP 526 -- Syntax for Variable Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/).

Comment: the old, python 2 equivalent of this would be: `model = a_function(f) # type: Class`. python 3 added support for placing the type hint after the variable name, rather than in a comment at the end of the line. that's all. nothing happens at compile or run time except the type hint information is recorded and accessible for use by third parties in the `__annotations__` global (e.g., `{'model': <class 'Class'>}`).

Answer (score 3):

It’s a [type annotation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). It doesn’t actually *do* anything in code, but the annotation can be read by third-party applications (e.g. mypy) to perform type checking. In your case, the code declares that the type of the variable `model` is `Class`.

The rest of the expression is a regular assignment.

Answer (score 2):

The following statement that you posted:

```
model: Class = a_function(f)
```

Means a variable declared with its type. This rule is not required in Python, but it's a way to show what is the type of the parameter or variable that is being used. This property is called a "[type_annotation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)". It can be useful, for example, in complex functions implementations, such as the following code:

```
def process_some_data(client: str, properties: dict, feature: SomeClass):
   # some  code
   return something
```